# I'm trying to display images that I uploaded to my backend with multer

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, multer

I'm using multer to upload images from my react client. All the images are being stored they just aren't showing up. The images are being stored, but aren't showing up in react. The are set in state just not displaying. I can see them in the images folder on the backend so I know multer is working.

This is my react component

```
class AddNewDish extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            description: ''

        }
    }



    createDishHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('name', this.state.name)
        fd.append('imageUrl', this.state.imageUrl, this.state.imageUrl.name)
        fd.append('description', this.state.description)
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add-new-dish', fd,)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res, 'res')
            })
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }


    onChange = (e) => {
        switch(e.target.name) {

            case 'imageUrl':
                this.setState({imageUrl: e.target.files[0]});
                break;
            default:
                this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
        }
        console.log(e)
    }



    render () {
        console.log(this.state.imageUrl, 'in imgUrl')
        return (
            <div>
             <form onSubmit={this.createDishHandler}> 
                <input
                    label='Name'
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    name='name'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Enter Dish Name'
                    value={this.state.name}
                />

                < input
                    label='Dish Image'
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    name='imageUrl'
                    type='file'
                    placeholder='Enter Dish Image'
                    // value={this.state.imageUrl}
                />

                 <input
                    label='Description'
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    name='description'
                    placeholder='Enter Dish Description'
                    type='text'
                    value={this.state.description}
                />
                <img src={this.state.imageUrl}/>
                 <button>Submit Dish</button> 
             </form> 
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default AddNewDish
```

One the backend

```
const multer = require('multer');

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(
        file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || 
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
        ) {
            cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cd(null, false)
    }
}
exports.upload = multer({

        storage: fileStorage, 
        fileFilter: fileFilter
    })
        .single('imageUrl')
```

This is how I call my route

```
exports.postADish = async  ( req, res,) => {
    console.log(req.file, 'in req.file')

    try {
        const { name,  description } = req.body;
        const imageUrl = req.file.path

            const newDish = await dish.postNewDish({name, description, imageUrl})
            res.status(201).json(`new dish added`)

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(`Error posting dish`)
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

How I use upload middleware

```
router.post('/add-new-dish', dishController.upload, dishController.postADish);
```

making folder public

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
```

This is how I'm trying to display the images in my index route on the frontend

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: []

    }

  }

    componentDidMount()  {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/`)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res, 'response')
          this.setState({
            data: res.data.dishData
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
  }


  render() {
   console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Nav

         <Route
            exact path ='/'
            render={props =>
              <Home 
                {...props}
                dishes={this.state.data}

              />
            }
          />
```

My state looks like this

```
{id: 7, name: "test dish", imageUrl: "public/2019-04-20T22:52:09.900Z-20190411_112505.jpg", description: "test description"}
```

I'm getting back the imageUrl and using it in the home component like this

```
const Home = (props) => {
    return (
        <DishWrapper>
            <DishContent>
           {props.dishes.map(dish => {
               console.log(dish, 'in dish')
               return (

                   <Dish key={dish.id}>
                        <h3>{dish.name}</h3>
                        <img src={ `public/${dish.imageUrl}`} alt={dish.name}/>
                        <h5>{dish.description}</h5>
                   </Dish>

               )
           })}
            </DishContent>
        </DishWrapper>
    )
};

export default Home
```

In the backend my get looks like this

```
exports.getDishes = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dishData = await dish.getDishes()
        if(!dishData) {
            res.status(404).json(`No dishes available at this time`)
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                dishData, 

            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are sending an imageUrl from your component in your axios call to multer and then adding a date string to the filename before uploading is that correct?  If so you need to return that filename in your res and use that as the image src.  What do you get when you console log req.file in your route do you get the updated filename?

Comment: This is what I get in my req.file console log ```{ fieldname: 'imageUrl',
  originalname: '20190411_112542.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'images',
  filename: '2019-04-20T01:00:07.965Z-.jpg',
  path: 'images/2019-04-20T01:00:07.965Z-.jpg',
  size: 2361225 } ```

Comment: So in my .json I should be sending the imageUrl?

Comment: So I just noticed that after uploading the image you change the page to the index.  Are you having trouble viewing the image before you click the submit button or after?  If its before you need to take a different approach if its after then you need to send the images filename back in your res.

Comment: I'm having trouble viewing the image both before and after

Answer (score 0):

So to view the image before the the upload you need to first use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) which is a javascript object that lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files.  This will give you a base64 version of your image that you can add to your image src.  So you can do this in your onChange function and it would look something like the following:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    switch(e.target.name) {

        case 'imageUrl':
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                this.setState({
                    imageUrl: file,
                    imgBase64: reader.result
                })
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            break;
        default:
            this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
}
```

in this example i'm adding to the state the `imgBase64` key and adding the base64 value to it but you can use whatever name you like just be sure to add it to your state object.

Then to view it you can use this value as the image src like so:

```
<img src={this.state.imgBase64}/>
```

After that when you submit your image to multer you need to return the image's filename so you can access it after you upload it so in your route since it seems like your getting the correct filename back when you log it you can return it to your axios call and use it after that.  So in your route just send back a json object and use it.  So instead of `res.status(201).json(`new dish added`)` send something like the following:

```
res.status(201).json({
  msg: 'new dish added',
  imageUrl: req.file.filename
})
```

and then your axios call will receive this json object and you can access in your frontend afterwards like so:

```
createDishHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('name', this.state.name)
    fd.append('imageUrl', this.state.imageUrl, this.state.imageUrl.name)
    fd.append('description', this.state.description)
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add-new-dish', fd,)
        .then(res => {
            //you can set your res.data.imageUrl to your state here to use it
            console.log('Success Message: ' + res.data.msg + ' - Image File Name: ' + res.data.imageUrl)
        })
    this.props.history.push('/')
}
```

But in the above function I see that you push do a different page when uploading.  So if you push to a different page then you obviously aren't going to be using this state anymore so you will need probably need to just retrieve it from your database at that point from the new page.

Anyway I hope this helps and if you have any questions let me know.

P.S. I just wanted to let you know you may want to use `Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)` instead of `new Date().toISOString() + '-' + path.extname(file.originalname)` in you multer upload it looks a little cleaner without all of the colons and dashes but it's not necessary.

Edit:

So if you are going serve up a static folder with express then like I said in previous comments below you are going to have to use absolute urls to access your content.  React cannot access anything with relative paths outside of the public folder in your client. So if in your backends root you are going to have a folder named images then in multer you would set the destination to `'images'` with express you would serve up the static folder `app.use(express.static('images'))` and to access this with your image you would need to use an absolute url

```
<img src={ `http://localhost:8080/${imageUrl}`} alt={dish.name}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The image is now displaying, but not sending back to the backend. I'm getting a ```  Cannot read property 'path' of undefined ``` . It works fine in postman, but not on the frontend. I ```console log  (fd) ``` (the formDate) and it's coming back an empty object. Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: It's probably because I forgot to set the image file to the imageUrl in your state during the onchange function because you pass that as the file to the form data, sorry there was a lot there to go through.  I edited the answer to include that.  Try it and see what happens

Comment: I'm making a get to display the images in the home page, but the aren't displaying. I removed the push. It would was in the wrong spot. Sorry if I'm bugging you I've never worked with file uploads before. I edited my could to include the frontend and backend get request.

Comment: Where is the folder your uploading your images too?  It should be in the public folder.  If you place it anywhere else you won't be able to access it because if you cannot access anywhere else in your app through a url.  So if your images file is in the public folder then the image should look like the following `<img src="/images/yourimage.jpg"/>` but from the looks of it you are just uploading to the images folder that is in the same directory as your multer script.

Comment: The images folding is in the root of the backend, but not in the public folder. I thought by making the images folder static I'd be able to access it?

Comment: You need to be able to access your images through a url.  You cannot access anything in react through a url except the public folder.  You could make a route for it but then you would have to access it with an absolute url like `<img src="http://localhost:8080/images/yourimage.jpg"/>` but that seems kind of silly when you can just upload your images strait to the public folder.  So in multer where you set your destination set just point it to the public folder.  If you have a client folder where react is it would be `'./client/public/images/'` or something to that effect.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I'm accessing it from the home component like so ``` <img src={ `public/${dish.imageUrl}`} alt={dish.name}/> ``` I edited the question to include the update to the static folder and multer.

Comment: my react is in a completely different file. They don't share the same directory

Comment: I added an edit to the bottom of my answer check it out but like I said in a couple of comments before if you are going to access it from the backend you need to use absolute urls not relative ones react cannot access anything outside of the public folder with a relative url path.  Check the edit and let me know.